# Перегруппировка массива

Tags: javascript, typescript

Делаю простенький експлорер на ангуларе (то есть, список директорий, в которых могут быть свои директории, в которых текстовые файлы). Вопрос в следующем: я получаю с сервера такие данные (path - это путь папки, id'шники директорий-родителей):

```js
[
  {
    id: "6np5E3yyEISXLNX9muyt",
    name: "sec list",
    path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0", "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV"],
    type: "file",
  }, {
    id: "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0",
    name: "In aeroport",
    path: [""],
    type: "directory",
  },

  {
    id: "H6AvpwXc49v4oDRWSjym",
    name: "Delete",
    path: [""],
    type: "directory",
  },
  {
    id: "LQ73vVoTuw9xd40jMs3j",
    name: "Aeroport list",
    path: [""],
    type: "file"
  }, {
    id: "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV",
    name: "Bordery words",
    path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0"],
    type: "directory",
  }, {
    id: "jWeClRAw55Er8z0Ow9uq",
    name: "mail list",
    path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0", "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV"],
    type: "file"
  }
];
```

Как можно этот код перегруппировать в следующий (чтобы наглядно было, какая папка где находится):

```js
[
  {
    id: "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0",
    name: "In aeroport",
    type: "directory",
    children: [
      {
        id: "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV",
        name: "Bordery words",
        type: "directory",
        children: [
          {
            id: "6np5E3yyEISXLNX9muyt",
            name: "sec list",
            type: "file"
          },
          {
            id: "jWeClRAw55Er8z0Ow9uq",
            name: "mail list",
            type: "file"
          }
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "H6AvpwXc49v4oDRWSjym",
    name: "Delete",
    type: "directory",
  },
  {
    id: "LQ73vVoTuw9xd40jMs3j",
    name: "Aeroport list",
    type: "file",
  },
]
```

Понимаю, что нужна рекурсия, но не могу даже приставить к чему именно ее прицепить. Рекурсивно перебирать  массивы path? Или есть другой путь?
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: А вот такой вот path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0", "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV"], велосипед само изобретенный? или уже присутствует в  проекте?

Comment: По сути тебе чтоб ответить на свой вопрос нужно  почитать вот этот мой вопрос который я задавал  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157033/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%81-n-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8 это часть ответа. И на базе этого метода в принципе можешь написать перебор и твоей структуры

Comment: само изобретенный)) Может у вас есть идеи, как сделать более правильно? Спасибо за ссылку, попробую

Comment: Да твой вариант мне тоже нравиться с path почему бы и нет.Сколько не смотрел в инете решение подобных задач, толком ответа и нет. И у тебя он очень даже интуитивно понятен.  Просто для человека он более трудно воспринимаем с кэшами MD5 или еще получаемыми чем то, машина разберет такие айди и все соберет это понятно.Я пошел по другому варианту, как в примере придумал адреса )) 0-1, 0-2, | 0-1-1,0-1-2,0-1-3 | 0-1-3-1

Comment: Допустим так.Разбирая подобный адрес и мне понятно что в чем лежит, и запрос на получение следующего узла легче отправить, типо дай мне что есть в 0-1-3-1, на сервере срабатывает функция которая проваливается по 0 папке 1 деле 3 потом 1 и там опять собирает данные уже из этой папки по сути моя функция вообще ни знает как называются имена папок она просто проваливается по номеру , и возвращает их клиенту, и они легко добавляются в нужный узел и вставляются.Но твой вариант мне тоже очень и очень приглянулся.Пока что пожалуй это лучшие 2 варианта которые я видел при построении деревьев.

Comment: Может есть и еще какие то, но все что я видел мне не нравились